# JDBC Delete & Insert using batch

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was wondering if it is possible to do both a parameterized DELETE and INSERT statement using batch. I am aware of how to insert multiple rows, however, I would first like to do a DELETE statement (Which requires different parameters).
Here is how I am inserting multiple statements:

```
        String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(FOO, BAR) VALUES (?,?);";

        PreparedStatement sql = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        for(...){
            sql.setString(1, fooValue);
            sql.setInt(2, barValue);
            sql.addBatch();
        }       

        sql.executeBatch();

        sql.close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For delete portion:

Use addBatch then executeBatch:

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
st.addBatch("DELETE FROM tbl1");
st.addBatch("DELETE FROM tbl2");
st.addBatch("DELETE FROM tbl3");
int[] results = st.executeBatch();
```

Then results will contain an array with the number of rows deleted from each table.

### For Insertion:

Here’s an example to show you how to insert few records in batch process, via JDBC PreparedStatement.

```
dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);//commit trasaction manually

String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
            + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?,?)";              
PreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

preparedStatement.setInt(1, 101);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong101");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
preparedStatement.addBatch();

preparedStatement.setInt(1, 102);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong102");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
preparedStatement.addBatch();
preparedStatement.executeBatch();

dbConnection.commit();
```

### Resource Link:

[JDBC PreparedStatement example – Batch Update](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/)

### UPDATE:

> Example/ Full Programs JDBC- Batch PreparedStatement - Execute DELETE
>   query using PreparedStatement's executeUpdate method in java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/** Copyright (c), AnkitMittal JavaMadeSoEasy.com */
public class PreparedStatementDeleteExample {
    public static void main(String... arg) {
           Connection con = null;
           PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
           try {
                  // registering Oracle driver class
                  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

                  // getting connection
                  con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                               "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",
                               "ankit", "Oracle123");
                  System.out.println("Connection established successfully!");             

                  con.setAutoCommit(false); //Now, transactions won't be committed automatically.

                  prepStmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE from EMPLOYEE where ID=? ");

                  //1) add set of parameters in PreparedStatement's object - BATCH of commands
                  prepStmt.setInt(1, 7); //substitute first occurrence of ? with 7
                  prepStmt.addBatch();

                  //2) add set of parameters in PreparedStatement's object - BATCH of commands                  
                  prepStmt.setInt(1, 8); //substitute first occurrence of ? with 8
                  prepStmt.addBatch();


                  //Execute PreparedStatement batch
                  prepStmt.executeBatch();
                  System.out.println("PreparedStatement Batch executed, DELETE done");

                  con.commit(); //commit all the transactions

           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (SQLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
           }
           finally{
                  try {
                        if(prepStmt!=null) prepStmt.close(); //close PreparedStatement
                        if(con!=null) con.close(); // close connection
                  } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
           }
    }
}
```

### OUTPUT:

```
Connection established successfully!
PreparedStatement Batch executed, DELETE done
```

In this tutorial we learned how to Execute DELETE query(DML command) using PreparedStatement's `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()` methods in java JDBC.

### Resource Link:

1. [JDBC Batch Processing (Batch insert, update and delete)](http://www.technowlogeek.com/programming/java/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing-batch-insert-update-and-delete/)
2. [JDBC- Batch PreparedStatement example- Execute DELETE query(DML
   command) using PreparedStatement's addBatch() and executeBatch()
   methods in java](http://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/07/jdbc-batch-preparedstatement-example_22.html)

Comment: @MattiBijnens Please check the updated portion. Hope it will clear your concern.